# chinese characters are getting corrupted as passed as query parameter values

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I am using Apache cxf library and implemented rest apis.

Below is the code sample code snippet. When I pass the term value as query parameter, it is corrupting the value, but when I pass the term value as request body, everything is working fine.

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
@Produces({ APPLICATION_JSON })
public UserSearch searchUser(@FormParam("term") String term, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {

}
```

When I hit the url like "https://{SERVER_URL}/search?term=求人". It is corrupting and the term value is not passed to 'searchUer' function properly.

But when I pass the 'term' value as request body, everything is working fine.

I would like to know the reason of corruption?

Comment: It is common practice to encode unicode characters in URIs.

Comment: I tried by encoding the values, but not working

Comment: Would you please show us how you tried to?